# What is the difference between brew install X and brew cask install X

Tags: homebrew

I'm familiarizing myself with the whole homebrew kit and the documentation is rather poor.
What is a cask, Cellar and a tap?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125468/what-is-the-difference-between-brew-and-brew-cask

Answer (score 354, accepted):

[Homebrew-Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/) is an extension to Homebrew to install GUI applications such as Google Chrome or Atom. It started independently but its maintainers now work closely with Homebrew’s core team.

Homebrew calls its package definition files “formulae” (British plural for “formula”). Homebrew-Cask calls them “casks”. A cask, just like a formula, is a file written in a Ruby-based [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) that describes how to install something.

The **Cellar** is where Homebrew installs things. Its default path is `/usr/local/Cellar` (`/opt/homebrew/Cellar` on Apple Silicon). It then add symlinks from standard locations to it.

For example, when you type `brew install git`:

1. Homebrew installs it under `/usr/local/Cellar/git/<version>/`, with the `git` binary in `/usr/local/Cellar/git/<version>/bin/git`
2. It adds a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/git` to that binary

This allows Homebrew to keep track of what’s installed by Homebrew versus software installed by other means.

A **`tap`** is a source of formulae. The default is `homebrew/core` but you can add more of them. The simplest way to create a formula for your own software is to create a GitHub repository called `homebrew-<something>`; put your formula file in it; then type `brew tap <username>/<something>` to add this new source of formulae to your Homebrew installation and so get access to all its formulae.

Some companies have internal Homebrew taps for their own utilities. There are a lot of public taps like [`atlassian/tap`](https://github.com/atlassian/homebrew-tap) for Atlassian software, or [`ska-sa/tap`](https://github.com/ska-sa/homebrew-tap) for radio astronomy. Homebrew itself used to have additional taps like `homebrew/science` but they deprecated them and imported the formulæ in `homebrew/core`.

Comment: formulae is the latin plural for formula, source: https://www.affixes.org/alpha/a/-ae.html#:~:text=Forming%20plurals.&text=The%20%E2%80%91ae%20suffix%20is%20used,pupae%20of%20pupa%2C%20a%20chrysalis.

Comment: and thus in english ( https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/formula ). I personally prefer the less-obscure "formulas", but Homebrew calls them "formulæ".

Comment: As a side note: the Homebrew [_installation directory_](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) is `/opt/homebrew` for **Apple Silicon**. So the default path for Cellar is `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` on Apple Silicon machines.

Comment: casks, formulae, taps... when a software becomes so common and widespread, a common and standard lexicon would make everything easier...

Comment: @AntonioSesto Agreed. It has been [discussed](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/41884) in the past but it went [nowhere](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/290#issuecomment-238813585).

Comment: @bfontaine. I see, thanks for the reference: it has been an interesting read. Where I work, plenty of visitors have been going to the wrong entrance and causing queues in another one for years. The signs are never blamed (and changed). Only the visitors are... because they do not understand the signs.

Answer (score 53):

I personally differentiate `brew` & `cask` just based on 1 of the main (if not the only main) differences, of **graphical GUI applications** being managed by `cask` rather than just `brew` (as @SwiftMango points out: that is mostly, but not always true). (There are other differences too which I don't know as much about).

Below is adapted from 'Graham Miln' on [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125471/192005):

### Homebrew

`brew` is the core command for the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) project.

> The missing package manager for OS X
>
> Homebrew installs the stuff you need that Apple didn’t.

Homebrew typically deals with command line software (*not graphical GUI applications*). Most of the software is distributed under an open source license.

### Cask

`brew cask` is an extension to `brew` that allows management of *graphical GUI applications*.

> Homebrew Cask extends Homebrew and brings its elegance, simplicity,
> and speed to OS X applications and large binaries alike.

Cask deals with a mixture of software and licenses.

Cask offers a way to command line manage the installation of *graphical GUI applications*.

### Licensing

Availability through `brew` or `cask` does not imply any specific specific license.

Comment: This is not always true but mostly.

Comment: Doesn't it get tad confusing with applications that can be both CL & GUI, like for instance R?

Comment: @radek I'm not sure how your rhetorical comment helps.  This is a decent rule of thumb, as SwiftMango constructively helped to point out.

Comment: Sometimes sources or builds between the two differ, such as Emacs.

Comment: Since you mentioned that "most" homebrew-core software is open-source (not all), I was wondering if you know any that is not.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from official docs:

### Cask

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask

> Homebrew Cask extends Homebrew and brings its elegance, simplicity,
> and speed to the installation and management of GUI macOS applications
> such as Atom and Google Chrome.

### Cellar

https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook

> Homebrew installs to the Cellar and then symlinks some of the
> installation into /usr/local so that other programs can see what’s
> going on.

### Tap

https://docs.brew.sh/Taps

> **Taps (Third-Party Repositories)**
>
> brew tap adds more repositories to the
> list of formulae that brew tracks, updates, and installs from. By
> default, tap assumes that the repositories come from GitHub, but the
> command isn’t limited to any one location.

Answer (score 3):

**Update on command:**

The current version of homebrew deprecated the "brew cask" syntax. From now on, se the --cask modifier instead.

```
brew <command> --cask
```

Comment: That is useful to know, but it does not answer any of OP questions here.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it