# Why is homebrew cask needed?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask

It doesn't explain why cask is needed, why not just use homebrew. Could anybody explain why it is needed? Why not just put all the cask packages into the bare homebrew? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cask started as a separate project according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46423275) and is primarily for graphical apps and packages that might not meet the [license guidelines](https://docs.brew.sh/License-Guidelines) for regular brew packages. [This comment on a Github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/7002#issuecomment-60494082) explains that the reason they're kept separate is that cask provides packages that are already compiled, and why that's important, namely, that the behavior of brew and brew cask are different, so should be separate.